# How to extend Nemerle with C# function that takes arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, nemerle

I want to create a function like `public static int Sum(int a, int b){ return 0; }` (in C#, not nemerle) that would be inside `.n` document (not external dll) and be visiable for nemerle code. How to do such thing? (cant find examples on the web)

Answer (score 3):

Nemerle allows class name in the using keyword for import static class methods.

```
module Functions {
    public Sum(a : int, b : int): int { a+b }
}

// or 
class Functions2 {
    public static Mul(a : int, b : int): int { a*b }
}

using Functions;
using Functions2;
using System.Console;

module Program
{
  Main() : void
  {
    WriteLine(Sum(2, 3));
    WriteLine(Mul(4, 5));
  }
}
```

Comment: Question was if it is possible to write C# code inside nemerle file in C# language not Nemerle?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my English is not good. Simple - no. Ncc use file extnesion to choose right parser for the whole file. But you can create macro for inline C# code and parse it by C# parser manually.

Comment: Just add your.cs file to the project.

Answer (score 1):

No. But you can create a partial class. One part of the class can be written in Nemerle, and other in C#.